# Adapter or Bridge in my specific situation?

Tags: api, oop, design-patterns, adapter, bridge

Well, I'm creating a library and that library needs to take all other libraries and make them work "alike".

For example: Imagine that I have 5 libraries, and all that libraries has the same idea, work to the same case, but they have their own way to work, their own API, and what I need is to make them work using a single API.

What is in my mind is to create a "factory" with a "trust list" inside of the factory that allows the user to choose different libraries to create, and the "factory" look on the "trust list" and if the library really exists, it creates and return the library.

But it can also be made using interfaces, where I can accept only classes that implements an specified interface, where I will have the security of the implementation of the methods that I want, so what this mean? All the libraries needs to implement that interface, implement the methods and make a kindle of wrapper to the library and that way they will work with the same API. The user can create a library using the factory and use the same API to all of them.

I don't know if you understand what I'm trying to explain, but I want to know, based on what I said, what is the best on my situation, "bridge" or "adapter" pattern?

And also, is my idea correct or am I crazy? (The interface and factory thing, and also the bridge and adapter, tell me what you have in mind).

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: So, is this library written in Java, PHP and C++? If not, please remove the non-related tags.

Comment: It doesn't matter, this isn't about languages, it's about "design pattern", implementation itself.

Comment: Then please do not add any programming language tag.

Comment: The question is that all languages that I put on the tags works with OOP. - What is the problem with that? :)

Comment: That's not how SO works. You ask a **specific programming question**, which means the specific programming languages you're targeting. When you target to multiple programming languages, you should at least provide the reasons about why are you doing that, and saying *because it works in all of them* is like saying *I have no idea what I'm doing*.

Comment: Did you realized that want you wrote doesn't make sense right? But it's okay. You already edited. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SH.0x90 if your question is not related to X language specifically (in some meaningful way) you should not tag this question as X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bridge pattern is designed to separate a class's interface from its implementation so you can vary or replace the implementation without changing the client code.

I think you can specify public non-virtual interface, then using Template Method in each of these public functions invoke implementation method.

```
class Basic {
public:
      // Stable, nonvirtual interface.
      void A { doA();}
      void B { doB();}
      //...
private:
      // Customization is an implementation detail that may
      // or may not directly correspond to the interface.
      // Each of these functions might optionally be
      // pure virtual
      virtual void doA { impl_ -> doA();}
      virtual void doB { impl_ -> doB();}
};
```

These lectures might be useful:

[Bridge pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge)

[Template method](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)

Comment: I thought, maybe I can create an interface "Adapter", that implements all the API that I want, and create a class that implements "Adapter" for each library, for example: "AAdapter", and receive the "Adaptee" (the library that I want to work with the API) as argument (the instance) on the constructor, and then implement the methods of "Adapter" on that "bridge" (AAdapter). Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: exactly, you will end with something like Adapter myA( AAdapter), Adapter myB( BAdapter)

Comment: I watched a tutorial about the bridge and the adapter pattern and the guy explained what I said for you, but I found one tutorial on Code Project that explain this nicely: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/595716/Adapter-Design-Pattern-in-Cplusplus

Comment: the important thing is you call a constructor on your base with an implementation as argument

Comment: Yes, this is what I wrote. I will to that because of a lot of reasons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like adapter to me. You have multiple adapter implementations, which is basic polymorphism and each adapter knows how to adapt to the specific library.

I don't see how the bridge pattern would make any sense here. You would typically use that in places where you use these libraries, but you don't know the specific library implementation yet.